# WAMP page unavailable

Tags: wamp, windows-server-2012-r2

I installed WAMP server on a Windows 2012R2. It works fine if I work on this device.

I putted WAMP online to use it on my LAN (intranet). I allowed the ICMP rules in the Windows's firewall but nothing appear when I try to access it with another device connected to the LAN.

Is Windows 2012R2 blocking something ?

Comment: You are a little short of detials here. How are you trying to access it from the other devices?

Comment: By typing the IP address in a web browser

Comment: Have you checked the Apache Access log to see if you are getting as far as Apache from one of these other devices `wampmanager->Apache->Apache access log`

Comment: I added a few rules to the windows firewall and it worked.